# Data type changes when saving a binary image

Tags: matlab, binary, type-conversion, grayscale

I converted a grayscale image to a binary image as shown in the script below:

```
D = '/folder-path/';
S = dir(fullfile(D,'*.jpg')); 
for k = 1:numel(S)
    F = fullfile(D,S(k).name);
    I = imread(F);
    I2 = im2bw(I);
    imwrite(I2,F);
end
```

The issue is when I try to read any of the images that were converted to binary and saved to the hard drive, the returned type is uint8!

I thought the image would contain two values like 0 and 255 for instance at least, but when running `unique(I)` on one image I got the following:

```
75×1 uint8 column vector

     0
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18
    19
    20
    21
    22
    23
    24
    25
    26
    27
    28
    29
    30
    31
    32
    35
    36
    37
    38
   217
   218
   220
   221
   222
   223
   224
   225
   226
   227
   228
   229
   230
   231
   232
   233
   234
   235
   236
   237
   238
   239
   240
   241
   242
   243
   244
   245
   246
   247
   248
   249
   250
   251
   252
   253
   254
   255
```

Why do you think this is happening? How can I read the saved images as binary and not uint8?

Thanks.

Comment: you're trying to save it as jpg, the problem here i think is the compresion that jpg inplies, that generate scales to aproximate "areas" of pixels.. you might try with 'png' (I believe it has no compresion) or just save the image as a matrix file...

Answer (score 1):

Do not write your binary image to a jpeg file, it is compressed and you certainly loose the exact values in the process.

In addition, erasing the source file really looks like a bad practice.

A solution would be to save your binary image in a png file with the same name. For instance:

```
imwrite(I2, [D s(k).name(1:end-3) 'png']);
```

In this case the png contains only zeros and ones. To be able to see your binary image in a viewer, better to have 0s and 255s:

```
imwrite(I2*255, [D s(k).name(1:end-3) 'png']);
```